# clickonce application install security warning administrator blocked

Tags: winforms, .net-4.5, clickonce, windows-7-x64

I have a WinForms .NET 4.5.2 clickonce application that was able to be installed or updated, until about a week ago.  At that point it started to pop up an "Application Install - Security Warning" dialog stating that the administrator has blocked this application.

[Clickonce Application Install - Security Warning Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/So1uB.png)

The environemnt is Windows 7, all machines are current with patches.

I have tested this on 3 different Windows 7 machines.  I only get the issue on one, call that machine A.

I have initiated the Clickonce depeloyment from

- a network share
- a local folder
- an internal IIS web site

I also have logins from two different domains (they trust each other). No matter which account I use to log into machine A, I will still get the error.  I can use either of my domain logins on machines B & C to deploy without issues.

Only one of my domain accounts is in the machine local administrator's group, which the other is not.  The domain account with local administrator rights is the same on all machines.

Again this worked on machine A as of Oct 6th, and hasn't worked since then.

I reviewed and tried everything I could find on SO, the MSDN ClickOnce forum, robindotnet.wordpress.com, a few books, and anything else I could find via Google, including Registry Settings, IE Security Settings, etc. I have used a valid certificate to apply an authicode signature to the EXE as well as the Clickonce manifest.

I have also enabled Clickonce logging and set it to be verbose.  The log file is never generated.  I suspect that this security warning is occuring before the actual Clickonce installer runs.

Any suggestions or solutions are welcomed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Someone on the MSDN Clickonce forum provided me the answer.  I needed to following the steps outlined in this kb: [How to: Configure the ClickOnce Trust Prompt Behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308453.aspx)